# How to play music from iPod in Macbook iTunes?

Tags: itunes, ipod, music

I would like to play music from iPod in MacBook's iTunes with wireless (over Wi-Fi).

Please advice how to setup to get that function.

Answer (score 1):

That feature is only available on iOS 5 for the iPad, iPhone, and iPod Touch. If you have one of these devices with iOS 5, connect your device via USB, open iTunes. After your device shows up, under the primary device tab (should default to it), towards the bottom, there will be a checkbox to "Sync this i(Phone, Pad, or Pod) over Wi-Fi." Check the box, and you should be set.

You must be on the same Wi-Fi, and have your computer on with iTunes open for it to actually sync in the future.

Comment: Also, when you remove your device from your computer, DO NOT eject it. Simply unplug the cord. Otherwise, it will disappear from the sidebar. You may need to sync the device before removing it, as well.